# Path wildcards in $route.path

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my application toolbar I want to show a back button when the user is on /manage/*.  If a user is on /manage or /other the back button should not show.

Here's my computed property to return true:false if the user is on /manage/*

```
computed: {
  showBackButton: function() {
    return this.$route.path === "/manage/*";
  }
}
```

The wildcards in the regex documentation on the vue-router site do not seem the work.  According to the documentation, * is the correct wildcard to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is making a type and value comparison, javascript does not work with regex by default... If you want to work with regex, I would rather try something like:

```
computed: {
  showBackButton: function() {
     return this.$route.path.match(/^\/manage\/.*$/);
  }
}
```